# Combine multiple records in a table into one field in another table based on fields in a third table

Tags: sql

I have three tables:

```
Table 1: 
pid, name, address  
1    Dale  BLANK

Table 2: 
pid, moid  
1    12

Table 3: 
moid, address  
12    123 Main   
12    12 South   
12    99 North
```

For output I need:

```
Table 1: 
pid, name, address   
1    Dawn  123 Mian,12 South,99 North
```

How can I combine multiple addresses in table 3 into one address field in table 1 linking the two tables with information in table 2?

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: Looks like you should consider using a PIVOT table -- depending on your RDBMS.  If not supported, perhaps a function could provide similar functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify what RDBMS you are using. In MySQL you can use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
select t1.pid,
  t1.name,
  group_concat(t3.address) Address
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
  on t1.pid = t2.pid
left join table3 t3
  on t2.moid = t3.moid
group by t1.pid, t1.name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bdc03/2)

Edit #1, if you want to `UPDATE` the table with this result, then the `UPDATE` statement will look like this:

```
update table1 t1
set address = (SELECT group_concat(t3.address)
               FROM table2 t2
               left join table3 t3
                on t2.moid = t3.moid
               where t1.pid = t2.pid
               group by t1.pid, t1.name);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13308/1)

<strike>If you are using Oracle 11g+, then you can use the [`ListAgg()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm) function:</strike>

```
select t1.pid,
  t1.name,
  listagg(t3.address, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t1.pid) Address
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
  on t1.pid = t2.pid
left join table3 t3
  on t2.moid = t3.moid
group by t1.pid, t1.name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b61b7/3)

In SQL Server you can use [`FOR XML PATH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190922.aspx) to get the result:

```
select t1.pid,
  t1.name,
  STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+ t3.address
         FROM table3 t3
         LEFT JOIN table2 t2
           ON t2.moid = t3.moid
         WHERE t1.pid = t2.pid
         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') Address
from table1 t1
group by t1.pid, t1.name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d6c11/2)

All of these produce the result:

```
| PID | NAME |                    ADDRESS |
-------------------------------------------
|   1 | Dale | 12 South,99 North,123 Main |
```

Comment: I am using mySQL.  Sorry for not mentioning that.  In my original question: "How can i combine multiple addresses in table 3 into one address field in table 1 linking the two tables with information in table 2?" I wanted to combine the multiple addresses in table 3 and put the results into table 1 in the address field.  What you gave me works GREAT but it is a Select statement and not an Update statement.  I really stink at mySQL.  Can someone please convert the mySQL statement above into an UPDATE statement to insert the results of this statement into the Address field of table 1. thx

Comment: @DavidBurke see my edit, I have updated the syntax to include an `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You do this with joins:

```
select table1.pid, table1.name,
       group_concat(table3.address, ', ')
from table2 join
     table1
     on table2.pid = table1.pid join
     table3
     on table2.moid = table3.moid
gorup by table1.pid
```

The function `group_concat` does not exist in all databases . . . other string aggregation functions are `listagg` and `ws_concat`.  Hopefully, you are not using SQL Server, because string concatenation is harder there.